# Compare IP to SQL table values

Tags: php, sql, ip

I am capturing the visitors ip address during a form submit using the following.

```
$users_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

What I would now like to do is see if this ip variable has been used before when submitting a comment, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Maybe a `like` SQL command?

Comment: Are you already storing their IP address when they submit a comment?

Comment: Side note just in case you don't know: this is unlikely to be terribly consistent, as most users' IP addresses will change very frequently.

Comment: Can you provide the schema for your table where the IPs are stored?

Comment: _Advice:_ convert IP addresses in long. It makes IP address comparisons easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you stored client ips in the table named: "ips" then use this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($your_db_host, $your_user_account, $your_password);
$mysql_select_db($your_db_name);

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "select 1 from `ips` where `ip`='$ip'";
$sql_resource = mysql_query($sql);
$mysql_close($connection);

if($sql_resource && mysql_num_rows($sql_resource) > 0){
    // your logic code if the ip existed in the db
    echo 'The ip has been used before';
} else {
    // code if the ip not existed in the db
    echo 'The ip has not been used before yet';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, nice routine :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial explaining how to store IP addresses in MySQL. In short, convert them to long like suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677783/compare-ip-to-sql-table-values#comment25752217_17677783), then use simple `SELECT` statement to find it:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE ip = " . ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```